# Magento 2 discount codes / shopping cart

Tags: magento2

Magento 2 discount codes / shopping cart Price rules only for non-reduced items, is that possible?
So I don't want to use the new code on a discount that has already been received.

Comment: Your question lacks clarity. Please provide more details to elucidate your intended action or purpose here.

Comment: I want a new one Cart Price Rules create, But the price rule should not apply to products that already have a discount.

Comment: What you want have the large scope like products have discount via cart rules, catalog rule , special price so it's quite tricky to handle this case. what you can do was handle this cart price rule priority or discard options.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this option where you set the cart price rule.

> Discard subsequent rules

This one Prevents any other pricing rules that may apply to a product from being applied

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand exactly what needs to be done!

Comment: Do you know where to set cart price rule. there you can find this option

Comment: I know where that is, should I turn it on or off!
https://prnt.sc/5BfV7ZOly843

Comment: yes , Now if this discount was used for one product , that product not gonna have other discounts.

Comment: No, that doesn't work

Comment: why?. do you have any other cart price rules

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149868/discussion-between-harun-and-tricksi).